# Should I (be able to) agree with a duplicate vote to a question with no good answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[How to do custom bokeh on Nikon D3200 with 18-55mm lens (f3.5)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71786/how-to-do-custom-bokeh-on-nikon-d3200-with-18-55mm-lens-f3-5) currently has one close vote as a duplicate of [Can I make custom bokeh shape using a 18-55mm Nikkor lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50107/can-i-make-custom-bokeh-shape-using-a-18-55mm-nikkor-lens) - but *I* can't vote that question as a duplicate because it doesn't have an accepted or upvoted answer:

[image]

Two very closely related questions:

1. Should I be able to vote for that question being a duplicate? I'm guessing the answer is "no", but in that case how did it get into the queue in the first place?
2. If I *should* be able to vote as a duplicate, should I actually be doing this to a question without a good answer?

Comment: I can't check, but do the second question's answers have downvotes? It maybe that when someone first voted to close, an answer had a score of 1, and it got downvoted later.

Comment: @muru You are (probably) a winner. There's one answer there which has both an upvote and a downvote. That still leaves the question as to what I should do when it comes up in the review queue...

Comment: I really don't have the expertise to judge the answers, but since you do, compare which of the answers to both these posts is worthy of an upvote, and pick the best among those, and vote to close in favour of the post with that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, answering my own question (with a lot of credit to muru):

What almost certainly happened here is that the potential duplicate had an upvoted answer and at that point it was marked as a duplicate. Probably due to the extra eyes the question now got due to being marked as a duplicate, somebody downvoted the only answer with a positive score so it was no longer a valid duplicate target.

The correct action in this case is to "Leave Open" as there's no good duplicate question (unless of course you can find another good duplicate, or think the question should be closed for other reasons).